# saving results from a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm having a problem saving the results from a for loop and am probably making a very basic mistake. I am trying to use a for loop to take the first letter from two columns and if either of them is a T then give a value for 'trail.type' of 'foraging', otherwise give a value of 'internest'. The code below works to do that, but then when I view each of the dataframes the column hasn't been added. Does anyone know why this might be?

The code I'm using:

```
dfs <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))

for (name in dfs){
  name$fromf<-substr(name$from,1,1)
  name$tof<-substr(name$to,1,1)
  name$trail.type <- ifelse(name$fromf=='T', "foraging",
                                   ifelse(name$tof=='T', "foraging",
                                          'internest'))
  name$fromf <- NULL
  name$tof <- NULL
}
```

The data I'm using:

```
from to strength
N1   N2   1.67
N1   T1   1.11
N2   N3   0.67
N3   N4   1.00
N3   N5   0.29
N5   N6   5.00
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Try `name$trail.type <- ifelse(grepl("^T", name$from) | grepl("^T", name$to), "foraging", "internest")`

Comment: Your code works for me: `trail.type` is added to `name` ?

Comment: @Phil Yes, it is a new column in `name`

Comment: Hi Phil. Sorry I should have made it more clear. dfs is a list of dataframes. So the script iterates through all of the dataframes by name adding trail.type as a column. However, when the loop is finished all I have is a dataframe called name from the last dataframe from the loop with the trail.type added, but none of the dataframes from the list have the column added.

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks! That is much nicer script than I had written to do that job.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I am trying to figure out how to do that

Comment: @RonakShah's solution tests for names that begin with T with pattern `^T` whereas you test for equality of names to `T`, see `?grepl` for for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if we have list of dataframes we can use `lapply`. For every list we check if the `from` or the `to` column starts with letter `T` and based on that we assign the values to the new column `trail.type`

```
lapply(lst1, function(x) cbind(x, trail.type = ifelse(grepl("^T", x[["from"]]) 
                              | grepl("^T", x[["to"]]), "foraging", "internest")))
```

where `lst1` is your lists of dataframes.

For instance,

```
lst1 <- list(name, name)
lapply(lst1, function(x) cbind(x, trail.type = ifelse(grepl("^T", x[["from"]]) 
                             | grepl("^T", x[["to"]]), "foraging", "internest")))

#[[1]]
#  from to strength trail.type
#1   N1 N2     1.67 internest
#2   N1 T1     1.11  foraging
#3   N2 N3     0.67 internest
#4   N3 N4     1.00 internest
#5   N3 N5     0.29 internest
#6   N5 N6     5.00 internest

#[[2]]
#  from to strength trail.type
#1   N1 N2     1.67 internest
#2   N1 T1     1.11  foraging
#3   N2 N3     0.67 internest
#4   N3 N4     1.00 internest
#5   N3 N5     0.29 internest
#6   N5 N6     5.00 internest
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much, that does exactly what I want it to do. I really should learn how to use lapply mapply etc.